# If you fly from JFK to LAX, will you see a murder?

Tags: geometry, statistics, expected-value

[The United States have a homicide rate about 10 times that of most countries.](https://www.macrotrends.net/countries/USA/united-states/murder-homicide-rate)

[WolframAlpha estimates that there are about 45 murders in the United States per day.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=murders%20in%20the%20united%20states%20by%20day)

[According to Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-far-can-your-eye-see-from-inside-a-plane) you can see a bit more than 350km far at the regular traveling elevation of an airplane (10 000m). On a flight from New York to Los Angeles which takes 6.5 hours you can therefore see at any moment in time a substantial part of the [contiguous United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contiguous_United_States).

I am therefore wondering what the expected amount of murders are that you "see" on this flight. By "see" I mean that the murder happens in your field of view as you look out of a passenger window. Assume you are looking out of the window the entire flight and you are able to use your full FoV of 135 degrees and nothing other than earth's surface obstructs your view.

Comment: Without calculating much , we can say that the chance to see a murder is extremely low since it must happen at the time you observe the place where it happens.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But it seems that if for 1/4 of the day I observe a large fraction of the united states and 45 murders happen that day, then the odds should not be very small? Why is the timing of the murder important?

Comment: If you mean that you "see" the point where it happens , without however being able to see what is actually going on , then yes , the chance gets considerable larger.

Comment: If you see a area of a circle with $r=350$ km you will at each times observe approx. 3.9% of the area of the US. If you multiply this with @Moo's number you get about 0.75.

Comment: @Peter, the question stated that "see" is defined in this manner. If you have ever flown across the United States, you probably know empirically that the inflight entertainment provides better chances of seeing "what is going on" in a murder.

Comment: It might be better to phrase it as "whether you have line of sight to a murder", although that then gets into a problem of whether an indoor murder counts.